DataContractSerializer handle missing enum values during deserialisation
Is there any way that I can handle missing enum values during Deserialisation of string enum values.
I originally thought that Json.Net and StringEnumConverter was being used by default for this conversion and wrote a subclass that can translate missing values, but from examining the stack trace it appears that EnumDataContract.ReadEnumValue is being used.
If there are changes in the enum definition I want to be able to handle on a case by case value what the value should deserialize to.
For example instead of receiving the below expected error because of a change to ConditionType, I would like to be able to specify a dictionary that gets used on failure i.e. {"TestComplete":ConditionType.InvalidValue}
UnhandledException caught (SerializationException): Invalid enum value 'TestComplete' cannot be deserialized into type 'ConditionType'. Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute attribute.

Any pointers on how to achieve this, or how I can hook into / override EnumDataContract
My enum member is marked as per below.
[DataMember]
public ConditionType Type { get; set; }

I did find a related question, but it doesn't really have an answer.

I haven't tested it, but this answer by Jason Shuler to Non-defined enumeration values in WCF service might be close to what you want.  It claims to handle invalid enums by by using an IDataContractSurrogate.  Does that work for you?

You wrote I originally thought that Json.Net and StringEnumConverter was being used by default -- DataContractSerializer serializes from/to XML.  Are you actually using DataContractJsonSerializer?  If so, what .NET version are you using?  Is it .NET Framework, or .NET Core?

Yes it is going to XML, some old comments hadn't been updated properly. This is on .Net Framework due to some dependencies on third party libraries.
I am still interested in a solution but its going to take me a bit to try and work out IDataContractSurrogate as from first glance it wont help with existing data., only going fowards. For what its worth I have ended up making some temporary conversion scripts that modify the suspect XML data before loading.

Ah OK as long as you are using DataContractSerializer I think you should be OK.  (surrogates were never ported to DataContractJsonSerializer in .NET Core as far as I know so you could have problems there.)  Are you using .NET Framework, or .NET Core?  Surrogates work differently in each.

Your immediate bug manifested in the exception information you provided (please, always provide comprehensive exception information, not only your source code sample) is the incorrect enum definition, missing [EnumMember] attribute. Unfortunately, you did not show your code sample where the bug is, but the bug is there.
Let's do the following: I'll show you a completely working code sample, so you can compare what's missing. Please pay attention for the correct attributes required. That should fix your problem.
Would you like to check it and compare? Please see:
namespace DataContracts {
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using FileStream = System.IO.FileStream;
using FileMode = System.IO.FileMode;

static class DefinitionSet {
    internal const string dataContractNamespace = "https/www.my.site.org/contracts/demo";
    internal const string filename = "demo.xml";
} //DefinitionSet

[DataContract(Namespace = DefinitionSet.dataContractNamespace)]
enum ConditionType {
    [EnumMember] Excellent, [EnumMember] Good,
    [EnumMember] Fair, [EnumMember] Bad,
    [EnumMember] StackOverflowQuestion, }

[DataContract(Namespace = DefinitionSet.dataContractNamespace)]
class Demo {
    [DataMember] // doesn't have to be public
    public ConditionType Type { get; set; }
}

static class DataContractDemo {

    static void TestSerialization() {
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new(typeof(Demo));
        dcs.WriteObject(new FileStream(
            DefinitionSet.filename,
            FileMode.Create),
                new Demo());
    } //TestSerialization

    static void Main() {
        TestSerialization();
    } //Main

} //class DataContractDemo

}
Notes:

Data Contract types and members don't have to be public. The members can even be private, moreover, this is the reasonable practice. In particular, it is very convenient to make an underlying field use to implement a property a part of the data contract, but not the property itself, and the property would be public or internal. The behavior of Data Contract is defined with attributes and does not depend on access modifies.
Pay attention that I carried out all immediate constants in the class DefinitionSet. In particular, it helps to keep the namespace of the data contract members the same for all your data contract types.

So, make sure you fix your enum definition. It should fix your problem unless you have bugs in other Data Contract types or member definitions. Please let us know if it fixes your problem and accept the answer unless you have other problems or further questions.
